# alert() not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert

[image: error]

'nuff said. I have absolutely no clue why using alert() there wouldn't work. It works perfectly in Firefox, but gives that error in Chrome.

Comment: Could you try `window.alert` (without invoking) and post the result please?

Comment: Maybe you overriden alert somewhere in code? `alert('foo');` works perfectly well in my Chrome.

Comment: @Xaerxess Wouldn't explain why it would work in Firefox though.

Comment: @alex: That's true, didn't notice this.

Comment: @pimvdb: `window.alert` in the console is apparently `null`

Comment: Sure would be nice to see a working http://jsfiddle.net/ of the problem. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
window.alert = null;
alert('test'); // fail
delete window.alert; // true
alert('test'); // win
```

`window` is an instance of `DOMWindow`, and by setting something to `window.alert`, the correct implementation is being "shadowed", i.e. when accessing `alert` it is first looking for it on the `window` object. Usually this is not found, and it then goes up the prototype chain to find the native implementation. However, when manually adding the `alert` property to `window` it finds it straight away and does not need to go up the prototype chain. Using `delete window.alert` you can remove the window own property and again expose the prototype implementation of `alert`. This may help explain:

```
window.hasOwnProperty('alert'); // false
window.alert = null;
window.hasOwnProperty('alert'); // true
delete window.alert;
window.hasOwnProperty('alert'); // false
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this seemed to do the trick. I have no clue what's setting `window.alert` to null though, even removing all the third party libraries I'm bringing in didn't lead anywhere. Strange.

Comment: @Charlie Somerville: Perhaps you have some kind of extension that injects scripts into webpages?

Comment: @pimvdb Turns out that the Chrome addon "Better Popup Blocker" decided that it's appropriate to set alert, confirm and prompt to null. Uninstalled.

Comment: interesting behaviour... `window.alert = null` can be fixed, but if overwriting the prototype method via `window.constructor.prototype.alert = null` there's no going back...

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue recently on my test server.  After searching for reasons this might be happening and testing the solutions I found here, I recalled that I had clicked the "Stop this page from creating pop-ups" option a few hours before when the script I was working on was wildly popping up alerts.

The solution was as simple as closing the tab and opening a fresh one!

Comment: This work for me as well, i disabled popup in chrome and forgot the action. Once i opened new tab everything is fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4158

> The problem is caused by javascript
>   method "window.open(URL, windowName[, 
>   windowFeatures])".  If the 3rd
>   parameter windowFeatures is specified,
>   then alert box doesn't work in the 
>   popup constrained window in Chrome,
>   here is a simplified reduction:
>
> http://go/reductions/4158/test-home-constrained.html
>
> If the 3rd parameter windowFeatures is
>   ignored, then alert box works in the
>   popup in  Chrome(the popup is actually
>   opened as a new tab in Chrome), like
>   this:
>
> http://go/reductions/4158/test-home-newtab.html
>
> it doesn't happen in IE7, Firefox3 or
>   Safari3, it's a chrome specific issue.
>
> See also attachments for simplified
>   reductions

Comment: The webpage isn't in a popup or anything, it's just a normal page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that does not need ajQuery and will enable alerts in a disabled iframe (like on codepen)

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i].setAttribute('sandbox','allow-modals');
}
```

Here is a codepen demo working with an alert() after this fix as well: http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/vNpoBr?editors=001

Answer (score -1):

put this line at the end of the body. May be the DOM is not ready yet at the moment this line is read by compiler.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>"
```