# Why can you delete an overridden property of window?

Tags: javascript

The `delete` operator removes a property from an object. If I set a property on `window`, I can delete it:

```
window.myProp = 10;
delete window.myProp;
```

As [the article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) I so often refer others to when it comes to the behaviour of the `delete` operator states, this is because property assignment does not set the `DontDelete` attribute (as opposed to variable declaration, which does).

That article also states the following (emphasis added):

> Note that it is during property creation that attributes are
>   determined (i.e. none are set). **Later assignments don’t modify
>   attributes of existing property**. It’s important to understand this
>   distinction.

Bearing that in mind, why can I override an existing property of window, `alert`, and then delete it to *return to the original value*? Am I missing something obvious? I rarely use the `delete` operator so that may well be the case.

For example:

```
window.alert = function() {};
alert("Hi!"); //Nothing happens

delete window.alert;
alert("Hello?"); //Alerts 'Hello?'
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKRYR/1/) to demonstrate that (only tested in Chome, pretty sure IE will not behave this way but don't have access to anything but Chrome right now).

Comment: `delete` on host objects is not to be relied on and doesn't work in IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [alert() not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184169/alert-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: I don't know but I like your question. I assume it's something like a CSS style on an element overriding it's inherited style, and if that element style is deleted via JS, it returns to the inherited style... you can only override it it is never deleted - just theory. Also, what would happen if you attempted to delete window.alert without having defined it as something else first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Chrome, the `window.alert` function is part of the *prototype* of the `DOMWindow` class, it's not a property of `window` itself.

Hence when you overwrite `window.alert` you're adding a *new* property to `window`, but the version in the prototype continues to exist, but is hidden.

When you `delete window.alert` the function in the prototype is re-exposed.

Here's some console output showing that the function is in the prototype:

```
> window.constructor.prototype
DOMWindow

> window.constructor.prototype.alert
function alert() { [native code] }
```

Firefox behaves similarly, albeit with different class names.

Comment: Ahhh I knew it was going to be something obvious that I was overlooking! Thanks.

Comment: @Alnitak Great Answer..@James we can also delete the alert property on prototype object but I would strictly oppose doing that..We should not modify the objects we don't own..So Ideally we should not delete alert property from window as well

Comment: Thanks for this. We have some incompetence to deal with: we can only add our code to the client's site in a particular element, can't touch scripts earlier on the page or put any code before they run. And earlier on the page a script has run which dumps language strings in the global namespace, including `open = "Open";`. Suddenly the Facebook SDK can't open dialogs on mobile. Your answer helped us rescue window.open.

Comment: Can you state if the answer is somewhat outdated? on FF 63 and Chromium 70 the `window.constructor.prototype` object has no reference to the `alert` `[native code]`, correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behavior, it's called shadowing. It permits you to provide custom functionality without wiping out the functionality of super classes. When you delete the method, your custom method is deleted, revealing the original method from prototype.

The deeper you go into inheritance and understanding the way prototype works, the more you'll find yourself seeing instances of people doing this.

Excellent question. This is not an area often explored by most JavaScript developers in my experience. If it weren't for this type of thing, many polyfills which extend or override the core functionality of JavaScript base objects wouldn't be possible.