# Chrome doesn't alert cookie, but Firefox does

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, alert

```
<html>
<head>
<title>cookie</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var user_name;
var del = new Date();
document.write(del.toGMTString());

function check() { 
    user_name = document.getElementById("user").value;
    del.setFullYear(del.getFullYear() + 1);
    document.cookie = escape("name") + "=" + escape(user_name) + ";expires = "+ del.toGMTString();
    alert(document.cookie);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
username : <input type = "text" id = "user"></input>
<input type = "button" value = "enter" onClick = "check()"></input>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Cookie doesn't want to alert in chrome, but it works in Firefox, but only displays a name of the user. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Does it alert anything in Chrome, and do you actually have a cookie set in Chrome?

Comment: what is the `document.write` for? What happens if you remove it? also, do you get any JS errors showing up in the browser's console?

Comment: only an alert box appears in the chrome, but it doesn't show any info stored in a cookie.It is empty.In Firefox it showes only name = name you entered but doesn't show the time

Answer (score 1):

Right I know this is quite an old question now, but I googled for the same sort of thing.

I am a penetration tester, so when testing for XSS and various other Javascript related attacks, alert is quite a common method that I want to use.

However, in Chrome, it seems very intermitant to when it wants to work.

Here is an answer that may help:

> window is an instance of DOMWindow, and by setting something to
>   window.alert, the correct implementation is being "shadowed", i.e.
>   when accessing alert it is first looking for it on the window object.
>   Usually this is not found, and it then goes up the prototype chain to
>   find the native implementation. However, when manually adding the
>   alert property to window it finds it straight away and does not need
>   to go up the prototype chain. Using delete window.alert you can remove
>   the window own property and again expose the prototype implementation
>   of alert.
>   Quote by "Matty F" - [alert() not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184169/alert-not-working-in-chrome)

I hope this helps!

**[Edit]**
Also, Chrome has a built in XSS filter on it, so when you do suspicious activity, such as alerting document.cookie, etc. Chrome filters out what it considers to be malicious. There are ways of turning this off if you launch Chrome with the --disable-xss-audit argument, however, that seems more hassle than it's worth, in my opinion.