# How to use switch with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have button like this:

```
<button>&divide;</button>
```

I want to use switch operator with string variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>      
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{  
  $("button").click(function(){
      var value=$(this).text();
      console.log(value);
    switch(value){

      case "÷":
         alert("OK");
         break;
      case "&divide;":
         alert("OK");
         break;
    }
  });   

}
);

    </script>   
</head>
<body>
<button>&divide;</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But none of those alerts appear on button click.console.log() shows:

```
"÷"
```

My browser - firefox 39.0.

Comment: `var value=$(this).text();`

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/5ebfy4wh/1/)

Comment: Are you able to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the problem? The cause might be something other than the code you've shown here.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: also check `console.log(value)`

Comment: Thank you, guys for help. I have made an edit.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem. It seems that you are getting the expected value in your console. Maybe you have [disabled alerts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277406/javascript-why-sometimes-alert-does-not-work-but-console-log-does) in your browser? Or there's some code elsewhere on your website that is [overwriting the alert function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388248/disable-alert#answer-4388291)?

Comment: I checked settings - all fine. And I pasted the full copy of the page

Comment: @ArslArsl `console.log(value)`  value???

Comment: @PranavCBalan console.log(value) shows   ÷

Comment: @PranavCBalan console.log(value.length) gives  1

Answer (score 1):

Consider that *Html Node Text* isn't always a safe source of truth... A good choise could be putting some attribute that gives you the information that you need and use views only for data presentation...

```js
function CheckBtnTextCtrl($) {
  let 
    $btns = $('button')
  ;
  
  function smartTextSanitization(text) {
    let decoder = document.createElement('textarea');
    decoder.innerHTML = text;
    
    return decoder.value;
  }
  
  function onBtnClick(event) {
    let 
      $btn = $(this),
      $btnText = $btn.text(),
      text = smartTextSanitization($btnText)
    ;
    
    switch(text) {
      case "÷":      
        console.log('it is division');
        break;
    }
  }
  
  $btns.click(onBtnClick);
}

jQuery(document).ready(CheckBtnTextCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>&divide;</button>
```

---

Good way (in my opinion):

```js
function CheckBtnCtrl($) {
  const ACTION_TYPES = {
    "SUM": 1,
    "DIVIDE": 2
  };
  
  let $btns = $('button');
  
  function onBtnClick(event) {
    let 
      $btn = $(this),
      action = $btn.data('actiontype')
    ;
    
    switch(action) {
      case ACTION_TYPES.SUM:
        console.log('ok, we need to sum values');
        break;
        
      case ACTION_TYPES.DIVIDE:
        console.log('ok, we need to divide values');
        break;
    }
  }
  
  $btns.click(onBtnClick);
}
jQuery(document).ready(CheckBtnCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-actiontype="2">&divide;</button>
```

Comment: Might be a bit premature to be using `const` and `let` in examples, considering few mobile browsers support them: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let

Comment: I support your *alternative* method of using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). But, can you tell what's causing the OP's specific problem?

Comment: The problem resides on the HTML Entities, as I said, they are not a safe source of truth... The example works only when you sanitize them (my first example), because you decode that HTML ENTITY. (when you query on dom... it can return an unicode, html entities, or something else depending on browser)...

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting info. But where can I find more about such unreliability?Please, if you able, provide me some resources about it. It would be very kind of you