# Alert() working but console.log() is not in Safari (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, console

Before you start to read: Its a Safari related Issue with Chrome it just works fine, so its not a general Problem but more OS related.

Im currently doing an Ajax call and I already started to pull my hair out because I was neither getting a log in the console for `success` or `error` in an `Ajax call`. I added a `alert("test")` and I finally got a message.

So now my question is why `console.log()` is not working but `alert()` is. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277406/javascript-why-sometimes-alert-does-not-work-but-console-log-does), but there its the opposite of what I have. Anybody can explain what I did wrong? Here is the code:

```
function AjaxFormSubmit(){
event.preventDefault() 
$.ajax({
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
    url :"/about/",
    type : "POST", 
    data :  1,
    dataType: "html",
    success : function(data) {
        alert("test");
        console.log('Success!');
    },
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log("fail");
    }
});
```

Im using Safari on Mac Sierra 10.12.5, never had this Problem, other `console.log` statements just work fine. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sorry edited the post. I used `alert("status"+data);` ...

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your developer menu is enabled in Safari preferences ( <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> )

[image]

AFter this, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to bring up the developer console. Click on the 'console' tab and you should see your message.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not have problems with other `console.log statements`. They all work except of this one. when I put a `console.log` above the function it gets displayed but when I use it in `success` it doesn't.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but unable to - I'm on El Capitan and Safari 10.1.1.. Just curious, can you try `alert(console)` and see if it alerts `[object Console]`

Comment: Yes I get an alert `[object Console]` when I `alert(console)` after success in the Ajax call

Comment: Sorry, could not be of help here. I did play with a bit, but works fine for me whatever I do.

Comment: Yes, I think its just a small bug, I will close this for now, If anybody experience the same Problem please leave a comment. Probably will be fixed on the next update.... 
@bajal thanks for your help really appreciate that you tried to reproduce the problem and wanted to help out :)

Comment: I have the same problem- not sure what it is, I see a bunch for 304 logs