# Javascript alert not displaying at all

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, alert

I have this function that should I think trigger an alert whenever one of the buttons in my page gets clicked, however nothing happens and if I open the console on the webpage, no errors show. why is it?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , () => {
         document.querySelectorAll('.new-button').forEach (button =>  {
                  button.onclick = () => {
                         const buttonName = button.innerHTML;
                         alert(`you have selected the button!  ${buttonName}`);
                  }

         });

});
```

I am using the ES6 version of JavaScript if that's any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alert() not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184169/alert-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: @Virx OP says there are no errors, so I doubt it's a dupe.

Comment: Is the script containing your code possible executed only after `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: I have alerts enabled, and other alerts work fine.

Comment: put an console.log just before alert and check if log is printed?

Comment: I'd add `console.log()` statements to make sure that the "DOMContentLoaded"  handler is being called and that there are in fact buttons on the page with that class.

Comment: console.log doesn't work. These buttons are added programmatically though, they are not there since the beginning of the loading page. is that why this event doesn't get triggered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dynamically add elements, you have to attach the `eventListener` to some ancestor element that was statically added. `document`works, but you can add more specific elements for performance. This concept is called **delegate listener**.

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.matches('.new-button')){
    const buttonName = e.target.innerHTML;
    alert(`you have selected the button!  ${buttonName}`);
    
    const newButton = document.createElement('button');
    newButton.classList.add('new-button');
    newButton.innerHTML = 'click me!!';
    document.getElementById('container').append(newButton);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="new-button">click me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think because the buttons I'm talking about are added programmatically by me, they don't respond readily as the stuff that is there from the loading part. How can I link these types of buttons to the event listeners?

Comment: I modified the answer for the specific problem.

Comment: this is how I added the buttons:
socket.on('connect', () => {

 
 document.querySelector('#add-channel').onclick = function() {
 var channel = prompt("enter new channel name here");
 if (channel != null) {
   socket.emit('new channel opened', {"channelName": channel});
    }
  }
});

socket.on('channel added', data => {

  const newButton = document.createElement('button');
  newButton.className = "new-button btn btn-dark";
  newButton.innerHTML = data;
  document.querySelector('#channels').appendChild(newButton);

});

Comment: ok the code in this answer works! however I don't understand the difference between my code and yours. Isn't .onclick also an event listener?
EDIT: I'll look into delegate listeners, thank you